preserve size of an HTML element at 0% of an animation [RESOLVED]
I'm trying to make an animation in css and for the first frame, so at 0%, I need the size of the element before his data-space attribute change before collapsing something like that.
Something like that
#settings {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 64px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 64px);
}

#settings[data-space=collapsed] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

#settings[data-space=collapsed][data-firstAnimation=false] {
    animation: collapseSettings 1s ease 0s 1 normal none;
}

@keyframes collapseSettings {
    0% {
      width: /*something to get the width before collapsing*/
      height: /*something to get the height before collapsing*/
    }

    /*...*/
}


If your starting state is 0x0 that should be the size of tle element not 50x50

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Oh sorry I forgot to specify but I have some elements in my #settings element that give a certain width and height to the element and I want to get that size.

If the dimensions of the element are determined by the contents you need JS to get that size, not CSS. But we need an [mcve] to help.

Sorry but I can't create a minimal reproducible example to show what I want because I'm looking for a way to do just that.

But when you said JS I think I found an solution to do what I whant using CSS variables and JS to get the element.offsetWidth

what you are looking for is most likely animation-fill-mode CSS property.
using this you can specify how your element will look like after the animation
so, you can do something like:
#settings[data-space=collapsed][data-firstAnimation=false] {
    width: /*something to get the width before collapsing*/
    height: /*something to get the height before collapsing*/
    animation: collapseSettings 1s ease 0s 1 normal none;
}

then you can add the final result of after the animation like this :
#settings[data-space=collapsed][data-firstAnimation=false] {
    width: /*something to get the width before collapsing*/
    height: /*something to get the height before collapsing*/
    animation: collapseSettings 1s ease 0s 1 normal none;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

or you can shorthand with the animation
animation: collapseSettings 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;

check: mdn docs for animation-fill-mode

I try to use it but I dosen't make what I want it dosen't keep the width and the height of the element before collapsing

i might misunderstood what you want to achieve , could you please re-explain the behavior you expect ?

I want to set a width and a height to my element at 0% of the animation witch are the width and the height of my element before his attribute data-space change to collapse (I change it using JS). Sorry if my explanations are bad.

so from what i understood you have an element, with a width and height, then you want at a certain point using JS to change the width and height and some other properties right  ?

No, so I have an element, with a width and height that are determined by the elements inside, and in JS I already change the "data-space" attribute from deployed to collapsed. And, I want to set, at 0% of the animation, the same width and height as when the attribute data-space is deployed.

tell me what you expect to see as a result, not what you how you are trying to implement it, because I can see a better approach but am not sure what you want exactly

So in short, I want to start the animation with the size of my #settings element when the data-space attribute is deployed so the size of my element with all these childrens and adding the padding and the gap

I resolved my issue using JS, before change the attribute data-space to collapsed I save in a JS variable the size of my element then I change the attribute and I start the animation setting the width and the height using CSS variables whitch are set at 0px and just before starting the animation I change value of my variables using the JS function document.documentElement.style.setProperty(). So it give me somthing like that.


const settings = document.getElementById("settings")

settings.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let width = settings.offsetWidth
    let height = settings.offsetHeight
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--width-init", width + "px")
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--height-init", height + "px")
    settings.setAttribute("data-space", "collpased")

})
:root {
    --width-init: 0px;
    --height-init: 0px;
}

#settings {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

#settings[data-space=collpased] {
    animation: settings-collapse 1s ease 0s 1 normal none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

@keyframes settings-collapse {
    0% {
        width: var(--width-init);
        height: var(--height-init);
    }
}
<div id="settings"></div>



